# Directive's template doesn't get value that's set by compile

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Please see this [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/xd3oV4aMsHqHsnNg7Q5k?p=preview)

I have an html that uses custom angular directive

```
  <body ng-controller="myCtrl">
    <h1>Hello Plunker!</h1>
    <div><sample attributeone="Sample Attribute"></sample></div>
  </body>
```

and my directive looks like this:

```
myApp.directive('sample', function() {
    var value = "";
        return {
            replace: true,
            restrict: 'E',
            scope : false,

            template: '<div>This is a sample Paragraph '+ value + '</div>',

            compile: function ( tElement, tAttributes ) {
              return {
                  pre: function preLink( scope, element, attributes ) {
                      console.log( attributes.log + ' (pre-link)'  );
                      value = tAttributes.attributeone;
                  }
              };
         }
        };
});
```

In my opinion, the `pre` of `compile` should execute bofore the template is returned and `value` should be set to `"Sample Attribute"`. But it's not getting evaluated.

**Expected Output**

```
This is a sample Paragraph Sample Attribute
```

**Actual Output**

```
This is a sample Paragraph
```

Is there any other way through which I set the `value` in template?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you just want to append `value`, then why not use your template as a function?

See this updated [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/6ZNAk9vpZ3VOrUZfZMNn?p=preview)

```
myApp.directive('sample', function() {
    var value = "";
        return {
            replace: true,
            restrict: 'E',
            scope : false,

            template: function(ele, attr, ctrl) {
              value = attr.attributeone;
              return '<div>This is a sample Paragraph ' + value + '</div>';
            }
        };
});
```